# Umbraco upgrade : Site just showing up "The website is restarting" message

Tags: .net, content-management-system, umbraco, upgrade, umbraco6

I upgraded Umbraco from v.6.1.6 to v.6.2.0. Republished all content. Deleted files/folder from TEMP folder.

Now, Umbraco is working fine, but wen I go tot the actual website, its just showing up "The website is restarting" message. I waited long time but no luck.

I checked the log and see a warning saying "Umbraco is not ready".

Any help on this issue is appreciated.

```
2018-02-08 14:37:56,299 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 10] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:37:56,366 [34] INFO  umbraco.content - [Thread 18] Loading content from disk cache...
2018-02-08 14:38:18,206 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 11] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:38:18,694 [34] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 15] Starting resolution types of Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Mappers.BaseMapper
2018-02-08 14:38:18,725 [34] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - [Thread 15] Completed resolution of types of Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Mappers.BaseMapper, found 20 (took 31ms)
2018-02-08 14:38:39,201 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 19] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:39:00,204 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 11] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:39:21,205 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 11] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:39:42,319 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 18] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:40:03,202 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 18] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:40:26,231 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 11] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:40:47,240 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 11] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:41:08,296 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 35] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:41:29,198 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 33] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:41:50,220 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 29] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:42:11,216 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 33] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:42:32,213 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 29] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:42:53,213 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 18] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:43:14,207 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 37] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:43:35,203 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 32] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:43:57,302 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 18] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:44:18,206 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 35] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:44:39,208 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 37] Umbraco is not ready
2018-02-08 14:45:00,204 [34] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 35] Umbraco is not ready
```

Comment: Any idea why "Umbraco is not ready"?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried republishing the entire Umbraco Cache?

/Umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?xml=true

Comment: Is there anything stopping you upgrade to 7.x?

Comment: I tried v7.0.0 and the same issue happened. Also there a few Datatypes that are not supported in v7